# Get index from a model array in Swift

Tags: ios, arrays, swift

I have a custom array like this

```
let moreMenuItem = [MoreMenuItem(title: "number1", imageName: "rate"),
                    MoreMenuItem(title: "number2", imageName: "followFacebook"),
                    MoreMenuItem(title: "number3", imageName: "email")]
```

and this is my model class

```
class MoreMenuItem {

    var title: String?
    var imageName: String?

    init(title: String, imageName: String) {
        self.title = title
        self.imageName = imageName }
    }
}
```

now let say I have a string "number3" and I would like to check if my array has "number3" in title. If it does, return the index where number3 is found. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Simple,

**Approach 1:**

```
if let indexOfItem = moreMenuItem.index(where: { (item) -> Bool in
        return item.title == "number3"
    }) {
        print("\(indexOfItem)")
    }
    else {
        print("item not found")
    }
```

**Approach 2:**

In case you dont want to compare simply a title string and rather want to compare two `MoreMenuItem` with based on their title, make `MoreMenuItem` confirm to `Equatable` protocol as shown below

```
class MoreMenuItem : Equatable {
    static func ==(lhs: MoreMenuItem, rhs: MoreMenuItem) -> Bool {
        return lhs.title == rhs.title
    }


    var title: String?
    var imageName: String?

    init(title: String, imageName: String) {
        self.title = title
        self.imageName = imageName }
}
```

Then use `index(of:`

```
let itemToCompare = MoreMenuItem(title: "number3", imageName: "email")
if let value = moreMenuItem.index(of: itemToCompare) {
        print("\(value)")
}
```

Hope its helpful :)

Comment: Nice! Works really well and the approach 2 is very helpful. Thanks!

Comment: Ops! Somehow I misclicked. Thanks again!

Answer (score 3):

Try this one liner using `index(where:)` method.

```
if let index = moreMenuItem.index(where: { $0.title == "number3" }) {
    print(index)
}
```

Comment: Works perfectly! Thanks!